# php and jquery cookie mixture?

Tags: php, jquery

hey guys,
i'm confused,
i have the following jquery script in my header:

```
forceAnim: <?php echo ($iphone || is_singular()) ? 0 : 1; ?>
```

which meanst, that either on the iphone or on a singular-type page forceAnim is 0.
However i want to include an additional query if a jquery cookie is saved.

if the jquery.cookie exists (and equals true) OR it's viewed on the iphone OR its a singular type post forceAnim should be true.

i have just no idea how to mix php with jquery in that case. to query if the jquery.cookie returns true i can just use:

```
if($.cookie('animate') == 'true'){
   //yes the cookie returns true.
}
```

any idea how i can query all three things?
thank you for your help.

Comment: "forceAnim should be 0", you mean? Otherwise the first and second paragraphs are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joel Alejandro's answer is incorrect (it accidentaly reverses the result of the first two conditions). Correct version:

```
forceAnim: (<?php echo ($iphone || is_singular()) ? 'true' : 'false'; 
           ?> || $.cookie('animate') == 'true') ? 0 : 1;
```

This is parsed by PHP to either of this (with true or false respectively):

```
forceAnim: (true || $.cookie('animate') == 'true') ? 0 : 1;
forceAnim: (false || $.cookie('animate') == 'true') ? 0 : 1;
```

So forceAnim will be 1 only if none of the conditions are true (and will be 0 if any of them is true).

Truth table:

```
A       B            C               D         E         F
iphone  is_singular  cookie_animate  (A || B)  (C || D)  (E ? 0 : 1)
0       0            0               0         0         1
0       0            1               0         1         0
0       1            0               1         1         0
0       1            1               1         1         0
1       0            0               1         1         0
1       0            1               1         1         0
1       1            0               1         1         0
1       1            1               1         1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
forceAnim: (<?php echo ($iphone || is_singular()) ? 0 : 1; ?> || $.cookie('animate') == 'true') ? 0 : 1
```

Comment: Not correct: this will e.g. incorrectly give a `0` when all three are false: `(((false || false) ? 0 : 1) || false) ? 0 : 1` is `((false ? 0 : 1) || false) ? 0 : 1` is `((1) || false) ? 0 : 1` is `0`.

Comment: I knew I'd have a problem with logic, yet the pattern looks something like that. Thank you @Piskvor for claryfing!